# Can't cd to newly added Path variable

Tags: environment-variables, paths

I added the following line to `/etc/environment`:

```
ML="$HOME/ml"
```

After I re-logged in for the script to take effect, running
`printenv ML` prints `$HOME/ml` and running `cd $ML` prints

```
bash: cd: $HOME/ml: No such file or directory
```

What is the correct way to set a new system wide path variable and be able to use it as a shortcut directory address?

Comment: Does the directory `~/ml` exist?

Comment: And what is the point of doing it this way? Why not do `cd ~/ml` without any variables?

Comment: `$` expansion is not done in `/etc/environment`. Use the full path.

Comment: @Pilot6 yes, it does.

Comment: @Zanna that link is for adding to the PATH variable. Here, I wonder how I can create a new path variable and assign a location to it.

Comment: and that link tells you: use `~.profile` or `/etc/profile`

Comment: use the full path, and preferably don't use `/etc/environment`, but `.profile` or if you must set it globally, make a file in the `/etc/profile.d` directory. You can use bash syntax there.

Comment: @Zanna thanks for your answers. I just used the full path and now it worked. Also, I think will now change to use ./etc/profile.d.

Comment: no worries :) have fun

Comment: @Zanna, sorry to bother you again, but I just added `ML="/home/minhtriet/ml"` and it did not work as running `printenv ML` after re-logging in prints nothing

Comment: where did you put it?

Comment: @TranTriet if you put it in some `profile` file, you also need to use `export`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/etc/environment` (or the user specific one -- `$HOME/.pam_environment`) is defined by `pam_env` PAM module, and in turn used by `login`, `ssh` and alike session startup programs to setup the startup environment for the user being logged-in.

`/etc/environment` does not understand any existing shell (or environment) variables, so `$HOME` in your case is being treated literally, no expansion is being done, hence the error.

You need to use absolute paths here e.g.:

```
ML="/home/foobar/ml"
```